# Cassandra: 2 required but only 1 alive & 3 replica were required but only 2 acknowledged the write

Tags: cassandra

I got two errors on write the data into Cassandra, want to know the difference between them.

1. 3 replica were required but only 2 acknowledged the write
2. 2 required but only 1 alive

Consistency Level is LOCAL_QUORUM.

As per my observations, When I got the first exception I see the data is written into one of the node, on second exception I do not see the data in any node.

Is my observation is correct, please help me on this.

Comment: Can you specify the replication factor of the keyspace, from the look of those two messages, the 1st looks like RF=5 the second RF=3. Can you clarify?

Comment: Total nodes in the ring are 4 and RF is 2, one of the node went down and i see some exceptions in application logs i.e second message (2 required but only 1 alive)
when i removed the node from the ring and i see first message (3 replica were required but only 2 acknowledged the write) when node status is (leaving).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to provide a clear answer without knowing the cluster topology and the keyspace replication factor. The full error messages + full stack trace are also relevant to know.

For `LOCAL_QUORUM` consistency to require 3 replicas to respond, it indicates that you either have 4 or 5 nodes in the local DC -- quorum of 4 or 5 is 3.

In the second instance, `LOCAL_QUORUM` requires 2 replicas when there are either 2 or 3 nodes in the local DC. And yes, quorum of 2 nodes is still 2 nodes meaning your app cannot tolerate an outage if either node goes down. For this reason, we recommend a minimum of 3 nodes in each DC for production clusters. Cheers!

Comment: HI Erick, thanks for your response, below are the cluster details.
DC1 - 4 nodes
Dc2 - 4nodes 
Topology- network topology
Replication Factor-2

I have observed second exception(2 required but only 1 alive) when one of the node went down in DC1, in this case the data is not written to the Cassandra.

when we removed the unresponsive node from the cluster we got first exception(3 replica were required but only 2 acknowledged the write) , in this case writes are success.

Just want to understand the difference between both the exceptions

Comment: It can't be `RF:2` because `L_Q` of 2 replicas is just 1. `RF:4` sounds more like it since `L_Q` of 4 is 3 replicas. For the second exception, the replica required doesn't change even when a node goes down. I suggest you review your configuration because the information you've given me doesn't add up. Writes can NOT be successful unless the "replica required" is satisfied. Cheers!

Comment: I am bit confused in this, L_Q of 2 replicas is just 1.  ---> N/2+1 --> 2/2+1 = 2 it will be 2 right (correct me here)

Comment: You're correct. That was a typo on my part. Cheers!